# Fixed irreducible representations of a finite group.

Tags: matrices, group-theory, representation-theory

Suppose $G$ is a finite group and $G$ has irreducible representations of degrees $n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_k$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$.

We say that $G$ has a fixed irreducible representation of degree $n_j$, if over any finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$, $G$ has an irreducible representation of degree $n_j$ for some $p\geq P$ (where $P$ is a fixed poisitive integer).

For example,  $S_3$ (symmetric group) always has a fixed irreducible of degree $2$ since, over any finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ with $p\geq 5$, $S_3$ has an irreducible representation of degree $2$.

My question is that given irreducible representations of a group $G$ of degrees $n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_k$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$, can we find out which of these degrees are
fixed?

Please inform me in case I am missing something. I am not aware whether the concept of fixed irreducible representations is defined in the literature or not.

Comment: Are you asking whether, if $\chi$ is any irreducible character of a finite group $G$ (as in complex character) and $N$ is any integer, whether there is a representation $\rho$ over some $\mathbb{F}_p$ for some $p>N$ such that $\rho$ realizes $\chi$, then the answer is "always".

Comment: No. My question is different from what you understood, probably.

Comment: Can you please explain the meaning of $\rho$ realises $\chi$?

Comment: For that you need the concept of a Brauer character. If I cannot understand your question, perhaps you need to have another go at writing it?

Comment: Suppose that $G=A_5$. Then over $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$, $G$ has an irreducible representation of degree $3$. However, $G$ has no irreducible representation of degree $3$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$. However, for any $p>5$, $G$ has a fixed irreducible representation of degree $4$ since $G$ has an irreducible representation of degree $4$ over any field. Suppose a degree of irreducible representation is given over a field. Can we see whether that degree is fixed or not? I hope that I am able to explain my question in a better way.

Comment: Since finite fields have prime power order, I recommend that you refer to finite fields ${\mathbb F}_q$ where  $q$ is power of a prime $p$, because with your notation people might assume that $p$ is a prime. Having said that, if $q$ is coprime to $|G|$ then the degrees of the irreducible representations of $G$ over ${\mathbb F}_q$ are determined by $q$ and the character table of $G$ so the answer to your question "can we find out ...?" is yes. An ordinary representation can be written over ${\mathbb F}_p$ for all primes $p$ not dividing $|G|$, if and only if its character is rational.

Comment: Rephrasing part of what @DerekHolt wrote, it seems that with your terminology $G$ has a fixed irreducible representation of degree $n_j$ if and only if $n_j$ is the dimension of a complex irreducible representation of $G$. So does your question amount to asking which of the dimensions of the irreducible $F_p$-linear representations of $G$ are the dimensions of irreducible complex representations?

Comment: @Stephen If I am interpreting the definition correctly, then it should be $G$ has a fixed irreducible representation of degree $n_j$ if and only if $G$ has a complex irreducible of degree $n_j$ with rational character values. You need the rational character values for the representation to be defined over all sufficiently large prime fields.

Comment: @DerekHolt Indeed you are right. For some reason I was wrongly assuming that the base field was algebraically closed of char. $p$. In any case, presumably the question is best studied in two parts: first ignore rationality questions, and then deal with descent from an algebraic closure. Perhaps the OP will clarify a bit now.